# Lambda function to pass value to API Gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, gateway

I am currently wrinting my masters degree and I am trying to built a gateway for Alexa to activate automotive functions in the car like switching on the light in the inside of the car.
Now I have already set up a custom skill, which asks the user for the color of the light he wants to switch on. The value is passed to AWS Lambda and the function checks if the color is available in a certain array. Then it responds the color with its unique ID back to the user.
Now my question is, can I pass this ID (just a simple integer) via the API Gateway to an empty website which then displays the number?
I did some research, but I only found some blogs explaining how to use the GET function in order to trigger the Lambda function.

There should be a PUT/POST method to put this value to a webpage (http), but I am not sure how to implement this into my code. (my code is in javascript /node.js)

Can somebody provide some basic help how this could be realized?

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you own web server, create a POST api which would take in the integer as parameter and store it somewhere(may a db) and then the web page can fetch it from there.

Comment: Thank you! Unforutnately I dont have an own web server, but isn't it possible to get a "webpage" through the api gateway with an executionable link? Can I put the integer onto this page?

Comment: To host this excutionable link you need a server. Maybe you can try writing it to a file and pushing the same to s3 or something and then sharing the link to s3(That too if you are sure about not hosting your own server)

Comment: Hi again! I managed to host a webserver with apache and run it locally in my network. Although I am not very familiar with webservers, do I understand your idea the right way? So now you want me to post the integer into a database via the API Gateway. Then you want a program to read out the value of the datapase and fill it into the index.html page. Then the website displays the integer? Are there any blogs or example code on how to get the value thourgh the API Gateway to a database? Thanks again!

Comment: Instead of apache I would use a node js sever with a mongodb, which would be much easier to setup (and you seem to be familiar with node). I can share project that I did is openly available. You can clone the same and change the api end points (and data models) and connect it to your mongo db. :) https://github.com/vizsatiz/rest-based-nodejs-backend or if you want a tutorial help with node https://www.guru99.com/node-js-mongodb.html

Comment: Thank you! I am currently trying to pass the value to DynamoDB from Amazon and then read out this value. Should be a little bit easier to do. The Node.js tutorial helped me a lot thanks for that! :)